# ImageButton not doing anything onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imagebutton

Within the application theres an imagebutton, which turns the flashlight on and off and if the the flashlight is on, then you can adjust the strobo frequency with a seekbaar, but when i tried running the application on my phone, then the imagebutton does nothing at all.
Heres the code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import static android.content.DialogInterface.*;

public class Flashlight extends AppCompatActivity {

CameraManager cm;
private ImageButton flashlightButton;
private boolean flashlightOnOrOff;
private String mCameraId;
int freg;
Thread th;
Strobo sr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flashlight);
    flashlightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashOnOffButton);
    flashlightOnOrOff = false;


    //Error if device does not have flashlight
    boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if (hasFlash == false)

    {
        final AlertDialog dialo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Flashlight.this).create();
        dialo.setTitle("Error");
        dialo.setMessage("Sorry your device does not have flashlight!");
        dialo.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialo.cancel();

            }
        });
        dialo.show();


    }
    cm = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {

        mCameraId = cm.getCameraIdList()[0];
    } catch (CameraAccessException ec) {
        ec.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Seekbar
    SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            freg = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


}

public void flashButtonClicked(View view) {

    try {
        if (flashlightOnOrOff) {
            flashlightOnOrOff = false;

            if (th != null) {
                sr.stopRunning = true;
                th = null;
                return;
            } else {
                turnOffFlashlight();
            }


        } else {
            flashlightOnOrOff = true;

            if (freg != 0) {
                sr = new Strobo();
                sr.freg = freg;
                th = new Thread(sr);
                th.start();
                return;
            } else {
                turnOnFlashlight();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ec) {
        ec.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class Strobo implements Runnable {
    int freg;
    boolean stopRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (!stopRunning) {
                turnOnFlashlight();
                Thread.sleep(100 - freg);
                turnOffFlashlight();
                Thread.sleep(freg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


public void turnOffFlashlight() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);
            flashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.offbutton2);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void turnOnFlashlight() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            flashlightButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onbutton2);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/offbutton2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/flashOnOffButton"
        android:background="#000"
        android:onClick="flashButtonClicked"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
        android:thumbTint="@color/Greeny"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flashOnOffButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: View this page http://stackoverflow.com/a/37316437/1770868

Comment: did you log something inside that button call back method.. first make sure that whether you get the event call back. then something...

Comment: Potentially silly question, but is the emulator or device you're testing on running Android M or N? Also, are there any errors logged in your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine but it'll run on devices with OS version after Marshmallow and you can run app in debug mode to check if it throws exception.

Comment: Ran it indebug mode, got no excpetion, but why it wont run on Lollipop for example?

Comment: because you have added a check if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {}

Comment: "mCameraId = cm.getCameraIdList()[0];" this API is not supported for pre Lollipop devices too